# SQL: update table using create statement

Tags: sql

I am using the following to update fields in my SQL table:

```
private String updateData(Handle handle, String username, String name, String table) {

handle.createStatement("sql/Create.sql")
            .bind("playername", name)
            .bind("tablename", table)
            .execute();
}
```

The Create.sql file is as follows:

```
UPDATE :tablename SET varname = :playername where name = :username
```

I know that it is not working because :tablename is a string variable. What code do I write for SQL to recognize the table name as if I actually typed it as hard code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What RLDBM (database program) are you using?  Best indicated by adding a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass table name as a parameter - only data can be passed. You need to change the string and "paste" the table name into SQL itself. **Very important note: you must make sure that the value of the `table` variable does not come from any kind of user input. Otherwise, you are opening up your code to SQL Injection attacks.**

```
String sql = String.format("UPDATE %s SET varname = :playername where name = :username", table);
handle.createStatement(sql).bind("playername", name).execute();
```

If the value of `table` does come from user input, change the code to use different hardcoded or pre-configured strings defined within your program.